# STRANGE: After saving a file named BD.jpg, a few minutes later it got renamed to: Good morning -darling ...!...-).jpg. WTH?

Tags: finder, filesystem, malware, virus

Yesterday a really strange thing happened to me. I exported 3 files via PhotoShop from the same .psd file: first CA.jpg, second HK.jpg than the third BD.jpg to a website's src project folder (loaded into Visual Code).

When I refreshed the browser (Chrome) to see the 3 images on the page I was currently working, the third image was missing from `/src’.

Went into `/src` to see what's up to realise that "BD.jpg" got somehow renamed to "Good morning -darling ...!...-).jpg" (in my native language).

How could this happen. Could this be the work of an intruder? I use my mac for dev. purposes only, haven't downloaded any other than the necessary apps for my web/coding projects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look under "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" -> "Text" and look if there is BD as a shorthand for a longer text. Might be this AND an error on Apple side I guess.

Comment: Anyway, this is crazy that osx uses these shorthands when writing to the filesystem. Could you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Might be Photoshop that does this or call a handler in the background which unexpectedly calls this shorthand function, idk. But please report this to Apple or Adobe as well to inform them about this.

Comment: Good idea! I will report this to Apple.

Comment: @muuvmuuv Text substitution is a standard functionality of all text entry fields, and sometimes quite useful even for file names etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look under "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" -> "Text" and look if there is BD as a shorthand for a longer text. Might be this AND an error on Apple side I guess. :)